# Hidden characters in comment

Tags: bug, comments

I just got claimed that my comment contains invalid characters. In fact. There were such characters. The string was:

```
`Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("JobName").getNextBuildNumber()`
```

And the characters were included after the "m" of "Number", see hexdump output:

```
e   x   t   B   u   i   � 200 214   � 200 213   l   d   N   u
```

What's going on here? The problem seems reproducible and it's clearly a server problem as I can see in firebug. While the input was correct (without such characters), this is the returned data from rest call which added the comment:

```
<code>Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(&quot;JobName&quot;).getNextBuildNu&zwnj;&#8203;mber()</code>
```

This is what I'm speaking about: [Changing Jenkins build number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645430/changing-jenkins-build-number/36901733?noredirect=1#comment79291483_36901733)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Those characters are:

- A [*"Zero-width non-joiner"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) (`&zwnj;`),
- Followed by a [*"Zero-width space"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (`&#8203;`)

They're added in long (inline) code blocks to allow the code to wrap to the next line.